# Cannot send push notification to FCM and to remote user from Spring Boot?

Tags: ios, spring-boot, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Okay, here's the thing, my colleagues have registered our backend app to `Firebase Console`. I'm using code bellow to send any notification to the `FCM` and consequently to the end user on `iOS`, but I'm failing to do so!

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/invoice/message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getMessage()  { 
    
            try {
                
                org.springframework.core.io.Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("name_of_the_json_file_below.json");
                InputStream dbAsStream = resource.getInputStream(); // when spring boot project running as a jar

                FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(dbAsStream))
                        .setDatabaseUrl("https://project_id_property.firebaseio.com").build();

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                FirebaseApp firebaseApp = null;
                List<FirebaseApp> firebaseApps = FirebaseApp.getApps();
                if (firebaseApps != null && !firebaseApps.isEmpty()) {
                    for (FirebaseApp app : firebaseApps) {
                        if (app.getName().equals(FirebaseApp.DEFAULT_APP_NAME)) {
                            firebaseApp = app;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
                }
                
                Notification notification = new Notification("title", "body");

                Message message = Message.builder().setNotification(notification).putData("title", "title").putData("body", "body")
                        .putData("type", "type").putData("sound", "default").putData("priority", "high").setToken("valid_push_token").build();
                
                if (firebaseApp != null) System.out.println("aaa"); //aaa
                
                String responseMessage = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
                
                System.out.println(responseMessage); //this prints -> projects/project_id/messages/0:1607085339665987%fbe62b14fbe62b14
                return;
                
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    return;

}
```

Within `resource` folder inside Spring Boot project there is a `json` file, presumably gotten at the time of registering out app with FCM.

This file looks like this:

```
{
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "project_id",
      "private_key_id": "some string with private key id",
      "private_key": "some long string with private key",
      "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-k202i@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "some client id",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-9cgqi%40project_id_string_property.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
```

As soon as some user from iOS mobile app login in, `User` table gets updated with new valid push token which is part of simple login request. That push token is gotten before the actual login request is sent to our backend app. Namely, request from user's mobile app is made to FCM and a new push token is pulled. This is usual scenario I guess.

For testing I just call local service (`Swagger`) `localhost8080:appName/admin/invoice/message`.

The mobile app is not getting any notification!

The problem is that all other services with very huge requests bodies, and bunch of check-ups are able to send notifications. Unfortunately, I cannot invoke them, bunch of cases and conditions need to overlap in some way to be able to reach the lines of code above for sending push notifications!

How to send notifications locally to an end User, assuming all configuration is correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is the function that is both sending sound to iOS and Android.

```
private Message getMessage(String token, String title, String body, String type, Map<String, String> data) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
    
    AndroidNotification androidNofi = AndroidNotification.builder()
            .setSound("default")
            .build();

    Aps aps = Aps.builder()
            .setSound("default")
            .build();

    ApnsConfig apnsConfig = ApnsConfig.builder()
            .setAps(aps)
            .build();

    AndroidConfig androidConfig = AndroidConfig.builder()
            .setNotification(androidNofi)
            .build();

    Notification notification = new Notification(title, body);
    
    Builder builder = Message.builder()
            .setNotification(notification)
            .setApnsConfig(apnsConfig)
            .setAndroidConfig(androidConfig)
            .putData("title", title)
            .putData("body", body)
            .putData("type", type)
            .putData("priority", "high")
            .setToken(token);
    
    if (data != null) builder.putAllData(data);
    
    Message message = builder.build();

    return message;
}
```